# Two sentences in passive voice

Tags: tense, passive

I have seen the following:

> Wann wird eine Entscheidung getroffen?
>
> Wann wird eine Entscheidung getroffen werden?

Are they both correct?
If so, what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: "werden" is used to form both the passive voice and the plural tense. And a passive future sentence uses it twice. (Sometimes language *is* perfectly regular and logical!)

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical tense of

> Wann wird eine Entscheidung getroffen?

is *Gegenwart* (*Präsens*) (equivalent to simple present tense in englisch).

The grammatical tense of

> Wann wird eine Entscheidung getroffen werden?

is *Zukunft* (*Futur I*) (equivalent to future tense in English).

As in English you can also in German use both tenses to describe events that will happen in the future. So in this case the name *Gegenwart* (as well as *present tense* in English) is misleading.

So in fact there is no difference in the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The sentences differ in tense, the first one being in present, the second one in future tense. They are both grammatical. Whether one of them or both are correct or interchangeable depends on the context.

Answer (score -1):

Both have the same meaning but the first example is more common.